# Wait for all iterations of foreach to complete in Angular when code in foreach returns observable

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

So I have a foreach loop on a bunch of rows and I'm calling API in this loop. Now I want to wait until all the iterations have been completed and observables from all iterations have been returned and then execute some code.
I have not used forkjoin since i want the data to be updated on the UI as and when the observable is emitted and dont want to wait until all the observables emit but at the same time I want to do some processing once all of them have emitted.

```
selected.foreach((row) => {
this.xyzservice(row).subscribe({
    next: .... do stuff....
}
)
})
```

Comment: Do you want all the observables to complete before moving on to the next step?

Comment: @danh itr returns an observable

Comment: @LaurenceIninda yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe for each observable (and update the UI if you want) then group all the observables and subscribe when they are all finished.

```
const observables = []
selected.forEach(s => {
  const observable = getObservable();
  observable.subscribe(result => /* Do what you want here */)
  observables.push(observable)
}

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(allResult => /* */)
```

You can also use the tap if you don't want to subscribe twice:

```
const observables = []
selected.forEach(s => {
  const observable = getObservable();
  observables.push(observable.pipe(tap(result => /* Do what you want here */)))
}

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(allResult => /* */)
```

Comment: i was skeptical about subscribing twice and felt that there would be a more optimal way to handle this

Comment: You can have as much suscription as you want but I provided a second solution avoiding another subscription by using the "tap" operator.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed explanation. i learnt a lot from it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for cycle and async/await pattern:

```
for(let i in selected) {
   var res = await this.xyzservice(selected[i]).toPromise();
}
```

You can also use `Promise.all`

Comment: I want to wait for all the observable iterations to complete, not a single one and not a promise

Comment: @ShreyPaiDhungat you can create an array of observable and then use forkJoin(this.observables).subscribe(values => ...);